# How can I make progress on the "stick it to ya" challenge?

Tags: ps4, mad-max

The challenge is to kill 15 enemies by using boarder spikes. I somehow have nine, though I'm not sure when or how I got them. Enemies never seem to land on the spikes when they try to jump on my car. I've also tried "nudging" them with the spikes, but it doesn't seem to count.

A bit of googling suggests that I need to find a vehicle full of boarders and kill them as they try to jump to my car, but I haven't been able to find any. I've finished everything else in the game besides a handful of combat challenges, so vehicles don't spawn very often in general.

What can I do to finish this challenge?

Comment: I achieved this without really realizing it or focusing on it, by getting boarder spikes early on. It can also happen during certain Death Runs, although I can't say for sure which ones have some boarding parties. I'm not sure of a way to get some to spawn either, that was one of my fears for the end game, fully realized.

Comment: I got them early on too and figured I'd finish challenges like this naturally, so I didn't worry about it. Do you know if you fail a death run, will it still count progress you made towards challenges? I have some specific arch angel challenges I was going to use death runs to do anyway.

Comment: I want to say yes? Although I haven't played it in a few months now.